# Change content of 2 textboxes based on listbox selection

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am creating a small tool which is split into 2 files:

`Form.ps1` - GUI & Button Events

`Main.ps1` - All functions

The form itself look likes the following:

[image]

When a user is entered and `Find User` is clicked, if there is only 1 result, then the `username` and `approver` are filled (approver is the users line manager) as follows:

[image]

However, if more than 1 result is returned, it will then create a `listbox` of the results.

The part I am struggling with is how to add the `approver` as well as the `username` using `$listbox.SelectedItem`

At the moment I can only get the `username` like the following example:

[image]

I am using the following AD Query to get the `Name`, `Email`, `Manager` and `ManagersEmail`:

```
  $searchResult = Get-ADUser -Filter "givenName -like ""$Firstname"" -and sn -Like ""$Surname""" -Properties Name, Mail, Manager |
                  Where { $_.Enabled -eq $True} |
                  Select-Object Name, Mail, @{Name="ManagersEmail";Expression={(get-aduser -property mail $_.manager).mail}}
```

The variables `$firstname` and `$surname` are taken from the textbox using a `split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WPF's element binding feature

I have filled the `ListBox1` with Items of string type, therfore it is binds directly no need to get the object's property.

Below is the sample XAML & Code.

XAML:-

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listbox1, Path=SelectedItem}" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="164,100,0,0" 
      TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

<ListBox x:Name="listbox1"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Height="100" 
         Margin="164,156,0,0" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="100"/>
```

C#:- Code behind file.

```
        listbox1.Items.Add("ABC");
        listbox1.Items.Add("XyZ");
        listbox1.Items.Add("123");
```

You can skip this C# part because you might already fill it by clicking on the Find User button.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a WPF frontend and PowerShell backend?

Comment: This change is meant to be done front end wpf. Try it once, then you will come to understand.

Comment: @ryanmaddock did you try ?

Comment: Yep I have got the part working now. The only thing I am struggling with is changing what is showing as the listbox items. It is currently showing the full hash table when I just want one part of that, however I will figure it out. Accepted your answer as correct, thanks for the help

Comment: Glad was able to help.